# ssh in local LAN: works with IP, but not by name

Tags: ssh, connection, dns

**On a local LAN, I am trying to ssh into a freshly installed Raspberry Zero WH, by host name.** I am connecting from an Ubuntu box.

The Rasbperry Pi does boot, and connects to the Wifi. I can see it in my PfSense firewall/router page "Status: DHCP leases" as up and running with it's IP address and host name. It's online and the lease type is static.

Now when I do

```
$ ssh pi@raspberrypi-zero-wh
```

I immediately get

```
ssh: connect to host raspberrypi-zero-wh port 22: Connection refused
```

However, I can ping it successfully ping it with this host name and immediately get a response.

```
$ ping raspberrypi-zero-wh
PING raspberrypi-zero-wh.my.lan (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.029 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.063 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.064 ms
```

I can also ssh into it by IP:

```
$ ssh pi@192.168.77.3
pi@192.168.77.3's password:
```

**Why does ssh work by IP, but no by host name?**

Note:

- It's different from [SSH works only with public IP but not with dynamic DNS hostname](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32046/ssh-works-only-with-public-ip-but-not-with-dynamic-dns-hostname) because this is all local, in the same subnet.
- [Can ssh internally, but can't externally: port 22: connection refused](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40224/can-ssh-internally-but-cant-externally-port-22-connection-refused) may be related, but I fail to see a link between a firewall setting when IP-based routing works.
- I use a PiHole on the same LAN, but again, the ssh seems to be rejected by the destination device, not the DNS server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You think that `raspberrypi-zero-wh` is that name of your Raspberry Zero WH, but as can be seen in the output of the `ping` command, that name resolves to `127.0.0.1`.

So you don't try to connect to the Raspberry Zero WH, you try to connect to the computer running the `ssh` command.

It seems to be a problem with the assignment of the DNS name.

Comment: Good spot. The name is given by the pfSense, which is NOT my immediate DNS resolver. As mentioned, a PiHole is, which uses the pfSense upstream. I'll look into the PiHole log to find more.

Comment: It was indeed a problem with DNS. In my DNS server (phihole), I had to whitelist the qualified domain raspberrypi-zero-wh.my.lan. Without that it had been blocked by my quite strict rules.

Answer (score 0):

`raspberrypi-zero-wh`
 Which I assume is your hostname is meaningless.

Try `raspberrypi-zero-wh.local` which should be resolved by `zero-conf` on a standard Raspbian and is supported by most Linux distributions.

Comment: Does your suggestion assume I am connecting from a Raspberry? I am connecting from an Ubuntu box TO a Raspberry.

Comment: I made no assumption, other than assuming zero-conf was on both platforms